# Windows 7: can zoom continuously follow pointer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, accessibility

Is it possible to make the fullscreen magnifier in Windows 7 follow the mouse continuously, instead of lurching when mouse gets to the edge of the screen?

Comment: Only in docked mode and lens mode does it follow the mouse centered. There is a way to get a psudo full screen mode that follows mouse by undocking it (works easily with 2 monitors) It is then in a window mode, but cannot select things the same as docking. There were 3rd party programs that were "better" than the win7 implementation long before win7 existed, some of them freeware.

Comment: Using alternative microsoft's official "ZoomIt" freeware utility will absolutely do what you want. Activate "livezoom" from this utility. [Download ZoomIt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897434.aspx)

Comment: @ISAAC I am on my macbook and away from my PC for a week. I will give ZoomIt a try when I return to my PC.